# Classification and Regression tree - optimal split calculation with GINI

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, classification

I have been following this guide for [cart](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-decision-tree-algorithm-scratch-python/) algorithm with my java implementation and was wondering if there is a faster way to chose optimal split.

The guide suggests these steps:

```
       for each feature:
          for each value of the feature:
             make a split
             remember GINI score if a split is less than previous min GINI
```

Is it possible to make any modifications on this procedure to gain speed at the cost of local accuracy, but which would not result with **overall** accuracy degradation ? While this can be easily parallelized, it's still costly to loop over each attribute and it's value to choose a single split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be sped up:

```
For each feature
    Sort data by feature
    Calculate cumulative counts of different values of target
    Calculate reverse cumulative counts of different values of target
    At each feature value
         Calculate gini value based on cumulative counts
         Keep the maximum
```

This can be further optimized if the features take on a limited set of values.  Instead of sorting the data, you can aggregate the data and use the aggregated data for the split calculation.

If the feature is categorical, you follow the same process but order by features by the target density for a binary target.  This becomes a bit trickier if you have more than 2 target values.

Comment: Couple of questions. Suppose i am doing binary classification into classes 1 and 0. By cumulative counts of different values of target you mean count of different value of a given feature ? What is reverse cumulative count and how is it connected with steps bellow ? At each feature value then assumes only unique features ?

Comment: The counts you want for a given split value are:  count(class = 1 where feature < x), count(class = 0 where feature < x), count(class = 1 where feature >= x), count(class = 0 where feature >= x).  Those are sufficient for calculating the Gini coefficient.  You can do these counts cumulatively, in 1 or 2 scans of the table.

Comment: Any links to other posts or references for when we have more than 2 target values ?